# How to determine if a non-English string is in upper case?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm using the following code to check for a string where all the characters are upper-case letters:

```
        if (preg_match('/^[\p{Lu}]+$/', $word)) {
```

This works great for English, but fails to detect letters with accents, Russian letters, etc.  Is \p{Lu} supposed to work for all languages?  Is there a better approach?

Comment: I always thought `\p{Lu}` was supposed to work for all Unicode-supported alphabets. Is it utterly failing to recognize any Cyrillic letters as uppercase?

Comment: Well, it works fine in Perl because Perl turns on `/u` automatically if the data is character data instead of byte data, or if it see a Unicode property in the pattern. Sadly it appears though that PHP isn’t using PCRE in Unicode by default. Is there a way to turn on `/u`everywhere else, like you can in Perl? BTW, you might still want to be careful with Unicode in ranges if it’s matching case-insensitively, as [we just recently fixed a bug](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=900689) related to that. I haven’t made the equivalent test with PCRE yet myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A special option is the /u which turns on the Unicode matching mode, instead of the default 8-bit matching mode. You should specify /u for regular expressions that use \x{FFFF}, \X or \p{L} to match Unicode characters, graphemes, properties or scripts. PHP will interpret '/regex/u' as a UTF-8 string rather than as an ASCII string.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html --

Answer (score 0):

using function u can do change in Uppercase of String ....
   Function Available here : 
                  string name="manish niitian";
                  console.Writeline("Your String in Uppercase is : "+name.UPPERCASE());